# Date formatting in JSP

Tags: html, date, jsp, simpledateformat

This is my JSP file content, which outputs to:

> Tue Oct 03 16:35:13 IST 2017
>
> ??/??/????

```
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>

<%  
 Date date = new Date();
 System.out.println(date.toString());  
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
 String strDate= formatter.format(date); 
 System.out.println(strDate); 
%>
```

Can you point out the bug?

Running environment: eclipse dynamic web project.

Comment: i'm getting `03/10/2017` . I dont think coding issue

Comment: As joni mentioned can you add `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>` encoding also ?

Comment: Did that , doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your locale must be using non-ASCII digits. If you expect to see 03/10/2017 you should change the locale for the date format, for example

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ROOT)
```

If you expect to see the date with localized digits, you should set the page encoding. (I forget how to do that on jsp)